# get field value in the same row where MAX(Field) LIMIT 1

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table called 'App' contains

---

```
ID | Name | Developer | price | downloads


1 | App1 | App Developer | Free | 5
```

---

i am using this code to get max downloads

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("$database") or die(mysql_error());

$mostappdownloaded = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(downloads) as maxdownloads FROM app")
or die(mysql_error());

while($infomostdownloadapps = mysql_fetch_array( $mostappdownloaded )) {
    echo $infomostdownloadapps['maxdownloads']; 
}
```

i want to get the developer field value from the row that contains max downloaded app

any help ?

Comment: But where is `Developer` field at your sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this with a subquery

```
SELECT Developer FROM App WHERE downloads = (SELECT MAX(downloads) as maxdownloads FROM app);
```

It can be possible that there are several records with the same max numbers of downloads

Comment: working like a charm , so if there more than one app have the same downloads number i'll face some problems right ?

Comment: thx, well I won't see it as a problem. If you don't care, you just pick the first in the list. If you care you can display/process them all.

Answer (score 0):

NO need to do fancy things just add developer in your query and you will get your desired output.

```
$mostappdownloaded = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(downloads) as maxdownloads,Developer 
FROM app ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Developer FROM App ORDER BY downloads DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the developer in which app has maximum downloads from the below query

```
select developer from app where downloads = (select max(downloads) from app)
```